# Is this "up your own ass" line spoken in Japanese forced, or is it a natural line one might say? [Shogun]

Tags: translation, word-choice, expressions

In Shogun S01EP02, a show set in the 1600s, the 太閤様{たいこうさま} (basically a great Japanese Lord) is on his deathbed. A Portugese Catholic priest advises that, unless the Japanese Lord receives the Sacrament, he won't be able to go to 神の国 (God's Kingdom).

Then, a woman in the court speaks to the priest: "神の国とやらはそっちの尻の奥にあるやもしれぬの" (officially translated as "Or maybe God's Kingdom is up your own ass..."). In English, this expression is completely standard. But is such an expression at all commonly used/standard in Japanese? To me, it feels like someone wrote the English line, and forcefully translated it to Japanese.

Am I being silly here?

Comment: Minor note, I feel the second-person pronoun used was probably [そち](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%85%B6%E6%96%B9_%28%E3%81%9D%E3%81%A1%29/), based on the vibe of the rest of the dialogue

Comment: Is it this one? https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHOGUN_%E5%B0%86%E8%BB%8D Then the original seems English, so it could be rather that 尻の奥 is a translation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

尻の奥にある is not an idiom or anything like that. It's difficult to interpret it even as a joke. If a modern Japanese speaker heard it, they would just be perplexed.

I don't know the story, but the drama seems to be based on [a novel written in English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dgun_(novel)). So perhaps the original English sentence was simply translated badly into Japanese. (Or, if everyone in the court understands English, the person who said it may have thought 尻の奥 would make sense as a parody of the English expression.)

Comment: No one in the court understood english besides those two (the priest and the woman). Though technically, they were speaking Portugese (it's understood that they were speaking portugese, even though the portugese dialogue is done in English). Anyways, glad to know I was right that it was just a localization goof. But it's odd, cuz the rest of the show, the Japanese dialogue is pretty spot on. and highlights how dialogue is lost/changed in translation. Which makes this instance all the more egregious/stand-out.